# ASP NET MVC4 Entity Framework SQL Query taking infinite time and not returning result

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have strange problem executing Stored Procedure.
The SP in SQL Management taking only 22 seconds. 
But from asp.net taking infinite time.

I have tried increasing command time-out property, but no luck.

This stored procedure is working if I directly select from table.

But when SP calls another SP which takes 22 seconds to process, and then returning to asp.net mvc is not working well.